# Update Custom Field value in Oracle Rightnow

Tags: custom-fields, rightnow-crm

I have 2 Text box Fields in Oracle Rightnow CRM Customer Portal
1.Account Balance
2.Amount to be Add

When i click pay button the second text box value is added with first text box value and sum will be displayed in first text box itself.

Can anybody help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague and there are many ways to perform event driven actions within Customer Portal.  What methods have you tried to achieve this so far?  Where did you run in to problems?  The [Customer Portal documentation](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/docs/february2014/olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm?context=crm&topic=developer_guide) is a good place to find information and examples that will help you with this type of question.

The general approach would be a custom form input widget that subscribes to an event handler that is fired from the custom pay button widget.  When fired, use a custom method in the account balance widget to get the value from the amount add field to perform your addition.  Then, set the value of account balance back to the sum of the two values.

Assuming that you are using Customer Portal v3, you would subscribe to the pay button event in that widget's `logic.js` file.  The examples below are pseudo code and would need to be altered to work how you need it to.

```
RightNow.Widgets.AccountBalance = RightNow.Field.extend({
    overrides: {

        constructor: function() {
            this.parent();

            RightNow.Event.fire("evt_payButtonClicked", this.addFields, this);
        },
    },

    addFields: function(){
        //Perform the work of adding the fields
        //Update the Account Balance field.
    }
}
```

In your pay button widget, you can then fire the `payButtonClicked` event from there.

```
RightNow.Widgets.AccountBalance = RightNow.Field.extend({
    overrides: {

        constructor: function() {
            this.parent();

            this.field.on("click", RightNow.Event.fire("evt_payButtonClicked"));
        },
    }
}
```